# Get link position on screen from google search results

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, html

I want to make an app in .net to search on google for a keyword and click on a specific link from the results. Like a bot.

How can I get the coordinates of screen where the specific link appears in search results so I can do a click on it. The component where the page loads will have javascript enabled so just parsing the html is not enought. It must look like a real user is clicking on the link.( it`s for a school project involving seo)
or What is the best approach to do this ?

Comment: Whatever you do, please do remember that there are legal issues around automating search engine result "clicking" in the area you are investigating. Please see "click fraud": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_fraud.

Comment: He could extract only the real URL from the click handler and use that to fetch the results.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be much easier to get a reference to the DOM element and simulate a click on that, instead of playing around screen coordinates?

Comment: I think google registers mouse movement throught page, so just simulating the click would make it invalid for what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the actual coordinates? If you are triyng to do this in C#, just get the HTML back from Google, and look through it to see how many results down the link is, wouldn't this be sufficient?? Screen coordinates does not seem very reliable (may differ for different people I think?)